# Getting a Name Error message in python

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I have scipy imported in anaconda and i called:

`from scipy import misc`

and called:

`data = misc.imread(/Users/Desktop...)`

to call the image from you desktop but i am getting the error message:

`NameError: name 'misc' is not defined`

Comment: `imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use imageio.imread instead.` - I realize it doesn't answer the question but you might try it.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
from scipy import misc
assert misc
```

Or

```
from scipy import misc
print(dir(misc))
```

Or:

```
import scipy
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
print(scipy)
print(dir(scipy))
```